# If statement scrapy xpath not working

Tags: python, if-statement, xpath, scrapy

Alright so I'm trying to match the result of an xpath selection against a few strings but I think I'm not getting the right result from the selection.

My code is the following:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="tab:specificaties"]'):
        category = sel.xpath('table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
        logging.warning(category)
        if category == "Videokaarten":
            logging.warning("Videokaart")
        elif category == "Geheugen intern":
            logging.warning("Geheugen")
        elif category == "Moederborden":
            logging.warning("Moederbord")
        elif category == "Behuizingen":
            logging.warning("Behuizing")
        elif category == "Processors":
            logging.warning("Processor")
        elif category == "Voedingen":
            logging.warning("Voeding")
        elif category == "Processorkoeling":
            logging.warning("Processorkoeling")
        elif category == "Barebones":
            logging.warning("Barebone")
```

So what I'm trying to do is check if the category matches the strings stated above and if so handle accordingly. The logging is only for checking the value of category which returns

```
WARNING:root:[]
```

in my terminal.

I hope somebody can shed some light on the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: normally when you extract from xpath, it's in a list, have you tried changing `if ... ==` statement to `if ... in ...:`?

Comment: The code has a [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Instead of enormous amount of `if` blocks, use a dictionary mapping `category` and a warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you extract from xpath, it returns the result in a list, you may try changing your `if ... ==` statement to `if ... in ...:`, something like this:

```
if "Videokaarten" in category:
    logging.warning("Videokaart")
elif "Geheugen intern" in category:
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I did what you said and tried changing it to if .. in category:
Yet I still get the `root:[]` response. I was under the impressions I had to get back a list as well so earlier I tried solving it by writing

`category=sel.xpath('table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()').extract().0`

I also tried that with `[0]` instead of `.0` but got back an index error. I think it said that the index was out of bounds.

Comment: @user2877036, can you show part of response from `sel.xpath(...).extract()`, I'm under an impression it's not returning anything

Comment: How should I check this? Through the shell or logging the `sel.xpath(...).extract()`? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: it's ok, just try `print category` before your `if...` statements

Comment: Ah it seems you're right since it seems to return `[]`.

Comment: @user2877036, yup. So first step you should make sure your `xpath` does return the results you want, and do the `if ... in ...` will get you sorted :) Or you can post the url which you're trying and I can take a look too